# How to run multiple beanstalk worker using php

Tags: php, beanstalkd

As of now, I am running only one beanstalk worker thread for my project, which handles both cron based jobs and real time jobs. So, I want to separate it out into two workers. One worker is used to track the cron based jobs and one more to track the real time asynchronous jobs. So that, the worker efficiency will get improve. Anyone can help me on this,

1. How to run and deamonize multiple beanstalk workers using php?
2. A sample script to handle multiple beanstalk workers?

NOTE: Currently I am using pheanstalk php lib.

Comment: And also how to watch multiple tubes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With pheanstalk, (or other libraries), if you want to accept jobs from a number of queues - just watch them.

```
$pheanstalk->watch('testtube')
           ->watch('tube2')
           ->watch('tube3');
$pheanstalk->reserve();  // get the next job from any of the tubes (+ 'default')
```

As for handling workers, I'm currently using [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) for some very similar scripts that I want to keep running. Its a python based daemon where the script you want to run is listed in a very simple configuration file. (adding more workers is literally changing a single number, and reloading the configuration).

One thing I have done is based on the blog post [running-the-worker](http://www.phpscaling.com/2009/06/23/doing-the-work-elsewhere-sidebar-running-the-worker/). Supervisord runs a shell script. That script runs the PHP which in turn returns a value (with `exit($x)`). If I return a value from the queue-runner, (for example), 99, I quit the shell script to shut down the worker. Another value may instantly restart the worker, Anything else, sleeps for a few seconds, before it restarts.

Comment: The above example to watch multiple tubes is fine. But the above script says, it should watch multiple tubes in a single worker script. Suppose if a want to restart a particular tube, how do I restart a particular tube? and How do I manage each and every tube separately?. Do we need to write worker script for each and every tube? If so, what about the startup script for multiple workers? How do I manage multiple worker script in the init.d?

Comment: What do you mean by restart tube?  It you want the same script to be be running several times, to watch individual tubes, for example, then start multiple workers, and maybe pass the tube-name to watch in, on the command line.

Comment: I mean, suppose if I am running 4 tubes in a single worker and in that, one of the tube having problem running the asynchronous jobs. for example, time based jobs. In that case, how do I stop and start that particular tube? But I got an idea from your last comment. If you explain me briefly about this then it will be fine.

Comment: I think there may be some confusion between workers and tubes. A tube does not "run" anything - it is just a queue where lumps of data are pushed in one end and pulled out by workers at the other end. It is the workers that pull the data out and process it. You can have any relationship between the workers and tubes you like: a worker watching one tube or multiple tubes; a tube being watched by one worker or multiple workers.